# TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined - Angular

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-geocoder, angular-google-maps

Whenever I send data to a method that geocodes the user's address for Angular Google Maps, I get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined`

---

> My code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gyvwjh

---

I have tried to look in the source packages to see if `geometry` is defined and it seems it is defined, but it's still not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `app.component`, when you call `getAddress()`, you have this check.

```js
if (google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { ... }
```

This does not do what you're thinking of. This test is always true. Hence you go on and call `result[0].geometry`, but there is no result. That's why you have `Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined`.

Change this test for this.

```js
if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { ... }
```

By the way, this will systematically execute the alert, since you have not set a google api key, so your request will always be denied.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was having this bug for 12 days, along with other ones with all this.